# How to make a media option or list in codeigniter CMS like wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, codeigniter, relation

How to make a relational table between articles, pages and media table in codeigniter so that while posting one can select images from media list like we do in wordpress.

Comment: take a look at CKFinder

Comment: I think in wordpress everything is post type so there is a table named posts which contains pages, posts, categories and some other things with different post types. If you want to do something like that than define one table for articles and pages and another table for medias to relate this table you can define another table which has many to many relationship with other two tables like posts_medias which contains it's own primary key and foreign key of posts and medias table.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, you said same table for Articles and Pages. Shouldn't I use two tables for them? If not, explain this please.

Comment: You can store article and pages inside single table named with a field name post type where you can mention that the post is either article or page or if you want to make a separate tables for that than its ok. For the reference you can check wordpress database.